# Recursive apply over DataFrame Groups causing reindex error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, pandas-groupby

I want to allocate some number of "units" over each group of a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
       limit  allocation  spaceLeft
Group                              
A        5.0         0.0        5.0
A        3.0         0.0        3.0
A        7.0         0.0        7.0
B        1.0         0.0        1.0
B        2.0         0.0        2.0
B        4.0         0.0        4.0
B        6.0         0.0        6.0
```

... which can be created by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[('A', 5.0, 0.0),
                        ('A', 3.0, 0.0),
                        ('A', 7.0, 0.0),
                        ('B', 1.0, 0.0),
                        ('B', 2.0, 0.0),
                        ('B', 4.0, 0.0),
                        ('B', 6.0, 0.0)],
                  columns=('Group', 'limit', 'allocation')).set_index('Group')
df['spaceLeft'] = df['limit'] - df['allocation']
```

The constraint is that the allocation of units must be as uniform as possible within each group's rows, but cannot exceed the `limit` for each row.  So, for example, if we have 10 units then the final, correct allocation to group `A` would be:

```
       limit  allocation  spaceLeft
Group                              
A        5.0         3.5        1.5
A        3.0         3.0        0.0
A        7.0         3.5        3.5
```

I wrote a recursive function to do this:

```
unitsToAllocate = 10.0
def f(g):
    allocated = g['allocation'].sum()
    unitsLeft = unitsToAllocate - allocated
    if unitsLeft > 0:
        g['spaceLeft'] = g['limit'] - g['allocation']
        # "Quantum" is the space left in the smallest bin with space remaining
        quantum = g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['spaceLeft'].min()
        # Distribute only as much as will fill next bin to its limit
        alloc = min(unitsLeft / g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['spaceLeft'].count(), quantum)
        g.loc[g['spaceLeft'] > 0, 'allocation'] = g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['allocation'] + alloc
        f(g)
    else:
        return g
```

If I manually, iteratively run the inner `f` logic on a single group like `group = df.groupby('Group').get_group('A')` then it works.  (I.e., it produces the correct result for `A` shown above.)

But if I invoke `f` as designed via `df.groupby('Group').apply(f)` it fails with:

> `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

What's going wrong?

And is there a more pandalicious way of approaching this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake in recursion logic:  *Both* branches of `f(g)` have to return a Group.

The following code works:

```
def f(g):
    allocated = g['allocation'].sum()
    unitsLeft = unitsToAllocate - allocated
    if unitsLeft > 0:
        g['spaceLeft'] = g['limit'] - g['allocation']
        quantum = g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['spaceLeft'].min()
        alloc = min(unitsLeft / g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['spaceLeft'].count(), quantum)
        g.loc[g['spaceLeft'] > 0, 'allocation'] = g[g['spaceLeft'] > 0]['allocation'] + alloc
        return f(g)  # <-- FIXED THIS LINE
    else:
        return g
```